# NSItemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier causing a memory leak?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks, share-extension

I have the following issue:

I am trying to share an image from Messenger (I have implemented a share-extension) to my application and I am using this code to load the image:

```
        [provider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:identifier options:nil completionHandler:^(id<NSSecureCoding>  _Nullable item, NSError * _Null_unspecified error) {
            if (item) {
                NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL*)item];
                if (isImage)
                    [images addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
                else
                    [images addObjectsFromArray:[self createImageFromPDFWithData:data]];

                [dataToUpload addObject:data];
            }
            count++;
        }];
```

Where identifier is **(NSString*) kUTTypeImage**. And for some reason this is causing a leak or something like that - it's entering **didReceiveMemoryWarning**. Note that this is happening only if I try to share the image using Messenger, if I try to share it from the Photo app, it's working fine. Can somebody give me an idea what to do in order to fix this?

Comment: Hi, have you been able to figure this out? I am having a very similar issue. It looks like iOS creates _EXItemProviderExtensionVendorLoadOperator objects in association with NSItemProvider objects. Even though NSItemProvider objects themselves don't leak, _EXItemProviderExtensionVendorLoadOperator objects do.